# Move x-axis (tick, labels and line) in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to move the y-position of the x-axis in highcharts? So far, I have only been able to move it to the top or bottom of my chart using

```
opposite: true/false
```

but now I need it to be in the middle of my graph, at a fixed y-value. My current code is

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Title'
        },
        xAxis: {
            opposite: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 4,
            reversed: true,
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            lineWidth: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            title: null,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            min: 1,
            max: 3.1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [
                [1, 1],
                [2.5, 1]
            ],
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [
                [1.5, 2],
                [3, 2]
            ],
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            name: 'name1',
            data: [
                [2, 3]
            ],
            type: 'scatter',
            zindex: 10
        }, {
            name: 'name2',
            data: [
                [3, 3]
            ],
            type: 'scatter'
        }, {
            name: 'name3',
            data: [
                [1.5, 3]
            ],
            type: 'scatter'
        }]
    });
});
});
```

My JSfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/5xum/fVpqU/7/ .

I want the x axis (along with the ticks and labels) to run through y=2.5, between the two different data sets. Does HighCharts support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `offset` property to move xAxis. In your case you have to use negative offset to move xAxis down:

```
    xAxis: {
                opposite: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 4,
                reversed: true,
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
                offset: -130
            },
```

Comment: Added: just figured out this is NOT exactly what I was looking for. It's sufficient, however it causes problems on resize. I still consider this an answered question, so thank you anyway.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
   
    },
  
  title: {
   text : <%=jtitle%>
  },
    

  xAxis      : { 
            min:Date.UTC(2016, 0, 0),
            max:Date.UTC(2016, 11, 1),
            //allowDecimals: false,
            type           : 'datetime',
            tickInterval   : 24 * 3600 * 1000*30, //one day
            labels         : {
                rotation : 0
            },
            
        },
      yAxis: {
      
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
            day: '%Y'  },
        labels :{
            formatter:function() {return  Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y',this.value);}
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 5,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },  
  
  series : [
  {
   name : 'MB Data',
   data : <%=datasp%>,
   tooltip: {
   valueDecimals: 2,
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    hour: '%H:%M'
   }
   }
  },
   {
   name : 'Date & Time',
     data : <%=datetime%>
   },

  
  ]
 });
});
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.